# How to append data to existed object's List in RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Yeah, I retrieved an object A from realm database, and A is a class has a property List, I want to append a new created instance of B to the list . But I don't want this happen on main thread. So, I use GCD to dispatch it.

My problem is that the `realm.write` block do not be execute. I have no idea about it. Here is my code snippet:

```
func savePomodoro(b: B) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { _ in
        let db = DataBaseMananger()
        let _ = try? db.realm.write({ () -> Void in
            let a = db.retrieveBigA()!
            a.bList.append(b)
            db.realm.add(a, update: true)
        })                
    }
}
```

A may look like this:

`````````````
class A: Object {
    ````````````
    let bList = List<B>()
    ````````````
}
`````````````

The `a` is the class A which has a `List<B>` named bList. The code inside write closure won't be execute.

Others:

Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)

RealmSwift 0.98.6 (cocoapod installed)

Comment: Maybe the write transaction fails and throws an error, what you won't see through using `try?`. I'd recommend using `try!` instead or have some explicit error handling.

Comment: I also tried use `do catch`, it's fine, didn't throws an error

Comment: If you have other concurrent transactions, e.g. if you write on one place from the main thread and keep that transaction open, this will block further transactions until the previous transaction was committed or cancelled.